# AWS: API Gateway and DynamoDB Integration - 401 Unauthorized Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I am facing an issue with an AWS API Gateway and DynamoDB integration. I have configured an API Gateway endpoint to retrieve all projects from a DynamoDB table. When testing the API Gateway using the AWS console, I can successfully retrieve the data. However, when I try to invoke the same API using tools like Insomnia, I receive a "401 Unauthorized" error.

Here is an overview of my setup:

- DynamoDB table name: test-dynamodb
- Primary key in DynamoDB: pk
- API Gateway configuration: HTTP method: GET
- Authorization: AWS_IAM
- API key required: true

**I have verified the following:**

- The API key value is correctly included in the request headers (x-api-key) when invoking the API.
- The IAM role associated with the API Gateway has the necessary permissions to access DynamoDB, including the dynamodb:Scan action on the test-dynamodb table.
- The API key is associated with the usage plan and the usage plan is correctly linked to the API Gateway deployment.

Despite these checks, I still encounter the "401 Unauthorized" error when invoking the API Gateway.

Can someone help me troubleshoot this issue and identify what could be causing the unauthorized error? Are there any additional steps or configurations I should consider?

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

```js
data "aws_caller_identity" "id" {}

data "aws_region" "region" {}

resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "apigw_dynamo" {
  name         = "apgw-dynamo-prod"
  billing_mode = "PAY_PER_REQUEST"
  hash_key     = "pk"

  attribute {
    name = "pk"
    type = "S"
  }

  tags = {
    Name        = "apgw-dynamo-prod"
    Environment = "prod"
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "dynamodb_api" {
  name = "apgw-dynamo-prod"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "dynamodb_resource" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.dynamodb_api.id
  parent_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.dynamodb_api.root_resource_id
  path_part   = "apgw-dynamo-projects"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "dynamodb_method" {
  rest_api_id      = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.dynamodb_api.id
  resource_id      = aws_api_gateway_resource.dynamodb_resource.id
  http_method      = "GET"
  authorization    = "AWS_IAM"
  api_key_required = true
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_usage_plan" "dynamodb_usage_plan" {
  name         = "dynamodb-usage-plan"
  description  = "Usage plan for DynamoDB API"
  product_code = "dynamodb-product-code"

  api_stages {
    api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.dynamodb_api.id
    stage  = aws_api_gateway_stage.dynamodb_stage.stage_name
  }

  quota_settings {
    limit  = 10000
    period = "MONTH"
  }

  throttle_settings {
    rate_limit  = 1000
    burst_limit = 2000
  }
}
resource "random_string" "api_key_value" {
  length  = 32
  special = false
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_api_key" "dynamodb_api_key" {
  name  = "my-api-key"
  value = random_string.api_key_value.result

}


resource "aws_api_gateway_usage_plan_key" "dynamodb_usage_plan_key" {
  key_id        = aws_api_gateway_api_key.dynamodb_api_key.id
  key_type      = "API_KEY"
  usage_plan_id = aws_api_gateway_usage_plan.dynamodb_usage_plan.id
}
resource "aws_api_gateway_gateway_response" "dynamodb_gateway_response" {
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.dynamodb_api.id
  response_type = "MISSING_AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN"
  status_code   = "401"

  response_templates = {
    "application/json" = "{\"message\": \"Missing Authentication Token\"}"
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_gateway_response" "dynamodb_gateway_response_403" {
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.dynamodb_api.id
  response_type = "API_CONFIGURATION_ERROR"
  status_code   = "403"

  response_templates = {
    "application/json" = "{\"message\": \"Forbidden\"}"
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "dynamodb_integration" {
  rest_api_id             = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.dynamodb_api.id
  resource_id             = aws_api_gateway_resource.dynamodb_resource.id
  http_method             = aws_api_gateway_method.dynamodb_method.http_method
  integration_http_method = "POST"
  type                    = "AWS"
  uri                     = "arn:aws:apigateway:${data.aws_region.region.name}:dynamodb:action/Scan"
  credentials             = aws_iam_role.api_gateway_role.arn

  request_templates = {
    "application/json" = <<EOF
      {
        "TableName": "${aws_dynamodb_table.apigw_dynamo.name}"
      }
    EOF
  }
}



resource "aws_api_gateway_integration_response" "dynamodb_integration_response" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.dynamodb_api.id
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.dynamodb_resource.id
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.dynamodb_method.http_method
  status_code = "200"
  response_parameters = {
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "'*'"
  }
  response_templates = {
    "application/json" = <<EOF
    #set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
    #set($projects = [])
    #foreach($elem in $inputRoot.Items)
      $projects.add($elem)
    #end
    {
      "projects": $projects
    }
    EOF
  }
}




resource "aws_api_gateway_method_response" "dynamodb_method_response" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.dynamodb_api.id
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.dynamodb_resource.id
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.dynamodb_method.http_method
  status_code = "200"

  response_models = {
    "application/json" = "Empty"
  }

  response_parameters = {
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers" = true,
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods" = true,
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  = true
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "dynamodb_deployment" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.dynamodb_api.id
  stage_name  = "prod"

  stage_description = "Production Stage"
  variables = {
    api_key = aws_api_gateway_api_key.dynamodb_api_key.value
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}




resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "main_api_gw" {
  name              = "/aws/api-gw/${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.dynamodb_api.name}"
  retention_in_days = 5
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_stage" "dynamodb_stage" {
  deployment_id = aws_api_gateway_deployment.dynamodb_deployment.id
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.dynamodb_api.id
  stage_name    = "prod"
  tags = {
    Name        = "prod"
    Environment = "prod"
  }

      access_log_settings {
    destination_arn = aws_cloudwatch_log_group.main_api_gw.arn
    format = jsonencode({
      requestId        = "$context.requestId"
      requestTime      = "$context.requestTime"
      requestTimeEpoch = "$context.requestTimeEpoch"
      path             = "$context.path"
      method           = "$context.httpMethod"
      status           = "$context.status"
      responseLength   = "$context.responseLength"
    })
  }

}

## dynamo role
resource "aws_iam_role" "api_gateway_role" {
  name = "apgw-dynamo"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

# dynamo access policy
resource "aws_iam_policy" "api_gateway_policy" {
  name = "apgw-dynamo"

  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "dynamodb:BatchGet*",
        "dynamodb:Get*",
        "dynamodb:Query",
                "dynamodb:Scan"
      ],
    "Resource": [
        "${aws_dynamodb_table.apigw_dynamo.arn}/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "api_gateway_policy_attachment" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.api_gateway_role.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.api_gateway_policy.arn
}


output "api_gateway_url" {
  value = "${aws_api_gateway_stage.dynamodb_stage.invoke_url}/${aws_api_gateway_resource.dynamodb_resource.path_part}"
}

## cloud watch for API GATE WAY:

resource "aws_iam_role" "api_gateway_cloud_watch_role" {
  name = "AmazonAPIGatewaysPushToCloudWatchLogs"

  assume_role_policy = <<-EOF
    {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
          "Principal": {
            "Service": "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
          },
          "Effect": "Allow"
        }
      ]
    }
  EOF
}


resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "api_gateway_cloudwatchlogs" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.api_gateway_cloud_watch_role.name
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonAPIGatewayPushToCloudWatchLogs"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_account" "api_gateway_account" {
  cloudwatch_role_arn = aws_iam_role.api_gateway_cloud_watch_role.arn
}


resource "aws_api_gateway_method_settings" "api_gateway_log_settings" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.dynamodb_api.id
  stage_name  = "prod"
  method_path = "*/*"

  settings {
    metrics_enabled = true
    logging_level   = "INFO"
  }
}
```